# Is it possible to use $_POST from an anchor?

Tags: php, html, post, input

I'm working on a retail type website and I have the search bar so that when you search for something it shows up in a grid with all the results.  Now, all the product names are going to be links that all lead to the same page (result.php) which is full of variables which are filled with the information of the product that was clicked.  How would I go about doing something similar to

```
$name = $_POST['productname'];
```

but with an anchor tag instead of a text input so I can use it to pull the MySQL data to fill in the page.  Is something like this possible?

Comment: with anchor you can use get passed parameters via `$_GET['parameter_name']`

Comment: where at in the anchor tag would i designate 'parameter_name' ?

Comment: `<a href="any.php?parameter_name=test">TITLE</a>`

Comment: in href attribute -> `<a href="http://myite.com/mypage.php?parameter_name=somtheting">`

Comment: @Akam so in my php if i use $_GET['parameter-name'] it will output "test" with that example?

Comment: Could you please list all pages involved and describe them? It's really difficult what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="filename.php?variablename=value">Click</a>
if(isset($_GET['variablename'])) {
   echo $_GET['variablename'];
}
```

if you use query string in anchor tag you cannot use $_POST.